# What is the Python rule about "unpacking" a generator

Tags: python

Here's a simple bounded generator.

```
def bounded_naturals(limit):
    num = 1
    while num <= limit:
        yield num
        num += 1
```

If I write

```
bn_gen = bounded_naturals(3)
```

`bn_gen` will be a generator object as expected.

But if I write

```
(a, b, c) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` will be 1, 2, and 3 respectively. That strikes me as strange since there seems to be nothing in the code that asks the generator to produce values. Is there a place in the Python specification that requires this interpretation?

Even more striking, if I write

```
bn_gen = (a, b, c) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

I get both results! `bn_gen` will be a generator object, and `a`, `b`, and `c` will be 1, 2, and 3. How should I understand what's going on?

Finally, if I write

```
(a, b) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

I get: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).`

If the compiler is clever enough to do these other tricks, why isn't it clever enough to ask the generator for only as many elements as needed in this case?

Is there a section in the Python documentation that explains all this?

Thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong about this and I can't try right now because I'm on mobile but your experiment would seem to indicate that you can either unpack everything or nothing.

Comment: `(a, b) = bounded_naturals(3)` in this expression how do you plan to later access the third element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unpacking operates on arbitrary iterables, not sequences, and it does so by iteration. When you do

```
(a, b, c) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

you are asking Python to iterate over `bounded_naturals(3)` and assign the results to `a`, `b`, and `c`.

---

A multiple assignment like

```
bn_gen = (a, b, c) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

works by assigning the RHS to each assignment target from left to right (*not* right to left like some other languages). The generator first gets assigned to `bn_gen`, then to `(a, b, c)`. Note that the unpacking exhausts the generator, so iterating over `bn_gen` will give you nothing.

---

When you do

```
(a, b) = bounded_naturals(3)
```

the failure has nothing to do with Python not being clever. Python will not silently discard extra values, as that would only hide bugs. The iterable must give exactly as many elements as the unpacking requests.

Remember, just because some code *could* be given a non-error meaning, does not mean it *should*.

---

All of this is documented in the [assignment statement docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Comment: A consequence that's worth mentioning is that your assigned generator will always be empty.

Comment: I wouldn't want "Python [to] silently discard extra values." What would be preferable would be a special rule in the case when the "object" on the RHS of the `=` is an iterator and there are multiple targets on the LHS. In that case, the iterator should be asked for as many items as there are targets. This would not "discard extra values." It would use the iterator as iterators are intended to be used. When some elements are produced, those that are no produced are still available for later production.

Comment: @RussAbbott: Then you can ask for that explicitly with `itertools.islice`, but if Python were to default to the behavior you want, that would lead to a *lot* of silently-discarded-value bugs. People thinking they'd fully unpacked something they hadn't would greatly outnumber people actually benefiting from the behavior.

Comment: Also, to support your desired behavior, Python would have to stop running the generator after producing the last requested value, instead of running it until it finishes. That would cause problems (especially on other Python implementations like PyPy) when a generator needs to perform cleanup, such as if it has `finally` blocks or `__exit__` methods pending.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica, I'm not following your reasoning.  Iterators are able to respond to `next()` requests. If an iterator on the RHS responds to `next()` requests until either it runs out of elements (in which case it generates a `StopIteration` error as usual) or runs out of targets (my case), the incompletely discharged iterator is still available for future `next()` requests. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @RussAbbott: Because people would think they had fully unpacked things they hadn't, and because if you stop a 3-element generator after the third element instead of running it until it returns, it won't release any resources it's holding.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you're looking is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> ```
> assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
> ...
> ```

> Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows.
>
> - If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma, optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.
> - Else: **The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list**, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.

I assume you're aware that a generator is an iterable. Let's see the code

bn_gen = (a, b, c) = bounded_naturals(3)

There are two `target_list`s here: One single target `bn_gen` and three targets `(a, b, c)`. Since `bn_gen` is a single target, whatever `bounded_naturals(3)` returns is assigned to it (in this case the generator itself). Then `(a, b, c)` is seen as a target list with multiple targets, the RHS (right-hand side) is "unpacked" and assigned one-by-one.

So yeah, as [@Pranav Hosangadi noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558665/what-is-the-python-rule-about-unpacking-a-generator/66558774#comment117661553_66558665), you can only unpack nothing or everything.